# Why is Scalas Either not a monad?

Tags: scala

I'm interested in knowing the design decisions why `scala.Either` was not done as a monad. There already exists some discussion on how to right-biasing `Either`, for example:

- [right-biasing Either](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-debate/K6wv6KphJK0)
- [fixing Either](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-debate/XlN-oqbslS0)
- [Fixing scala.Either - unbiased vs biased](http://robsscala.blogspot.de/2012/06/fixing-scalaeither-unbiased-vs-biased.html)

But there are mentioned too much details and I couldn't get an complete overview about why it is done as it is done. Can someone give an overview about the benefits of having a right-biased `Either`, about the problems to do it that way and about the benefits of not having an right-biased `Either` (if they even exist)?

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, but if you check out Scalaz's `Validation` that seems to be what you're looking for, more or less.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it just comes down to the [Principle of Least Astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). Using `Either` to encode success or failure is clearly something people do, but it is not the only use of `Either`. In fact, there is not much reason to have `Right` be success and `Left` be failure other than tradition. As adelbertc's comment above mentions, scalaz has `Validation` which specifically encode this.

To further justify the POLA claim above, take this code:

```
def foo(): Either[Int, Int] = Right(1)
def bar(j: Int): Either[Int, Int] = Left(1)
def baz(z: Int): Either[Int, Int] = Right(3)

// Result is Left(1) 
for (a <- foo().right; b <- bar(a).right; c <- baz(b).right) yield c
```

This compiles because I am using the `.right` projection in the `for` expression. It makes sense here the `Left(1)` in `bar` is the failure case and so that is the result, but imagine if `Either` was `Right`-biased. The above code would compile without the `.right` projections in the expression like:

```
for (a <- foo(); b <- bar(a); c <- baz(b)) yield c
```

If you used `Either` in your code to just be a "one-or-the-other" type, you would be surprised by (1) the fact that this would compile and (2) that it returns `Left(1)` and seemingly never executes `baz`.

In summary, use `Validation` if you want to use `Either` to encode success or failure.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this was the original reason, but there is at least one good reason.  In Scala, `for` comprehensions require more from the argument than that it is a monad in order to gain full functionality.  In particular, there are constructs like

```
for (a <- ma if a > 7; /*...*/) yield /*...*/
```

which require that the monad be a monad-with-zero (so you can empty it if the condition fails).

`Either` cannot sensibly be a monad-with-zero (save for `Either[Unit,B]`, where `Left(())` can be the zero).

One way to go is to say: okay, fine, just don't use your for-comprehensions that way.  Another way to go is to say: okay, fine, don't bother making Either a monad at all.  It's a matter of personal preference, of course, but I can see a certain lack of elegance in having `Either` (uniquely among the common monads provided in Scala) fall flat on its face once you try to use the full power `for` gives you.